# azure.ai.translation.document in Python - Cannot access source document location with the current permissions

Tags: python, azure, machine-translation

I've having problems with the azure.ai.translation.document library in Python. I have set up the translation service in Azure along with a blob storage with two containers. I've created my SAS connections using a 'User Delegation key'. One for source (Read / List) and one for target (Write / List).
e.g.
[image]

I tried running the Python program, but the file in the source blob was not translated an saved to the target blob.

I'm getting this error:
`azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidDocumentAccessLevel): Cannot access source document location with the current permissions.`

I've using this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/client-sdks?tabs=python

```
import os from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential from azure.ai.translation.document import DocumentTranslationClient

key = "<your-key>" endpoint = "<your-custom-endpoint>" sourceUrl = "<your-container-sourceUrl>" targetUrl = "<your-container-targetUrl>"

client = DocumentTranslationClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(key))

poller = client.begin_translation(sourceUrl, targetUrl, "fr")
result = poller.result()

print("Status: {}".format(poller.status()))
print("Created on: {}".format(poller.details.created_on))
print("Last updated on: {}".format(poller.details.last_updated_on))
print("Total number of translations on documents: {}".format(poller.details.documents_total_count))

print("\nOf total documents...")
print("{} failed".format(poller.details.documents_failed_count))
print("{} succeeded".format(poller.details.documents_succeeded_count))

for document in result:
    print("Document ID: {}".format(document.id))
    print("Document status: {}".format(document.status))
    if document.status == "Succeeded":
        print("Source document location: {}".format(document.source_document_url))
        print("Translated document location: {}".format(document.translated_document_url))
        print("Translated to language: {}\n".format(document.translated_to))
    else:
        print("Error Code: {}, Message: {}\n".format(document.error.code, document.error.message))
```

I'm using Thonny in Windows in an Enterprise Environment (as I'm still trying to learn Python). It's possible our cloud proxy is screwing with things.

Thanks

Loz

Answer (score 0):

instead of selecting HTTPS, select HTTPS and HTTP option, it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).